# Ruby C Api handling exceptions

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I am running a ruby script through C as follows:

```c
#include <ruby.h>

int main(void) {
  ruby_init();

  int status;
  rb_load_protect(rb_str_new2("./test.rb"), 0, &status);

  if (status) {
    VALUE rbError = rb_funcall(rb_gv_get("$!"), rb_intern("message"), 0);
    printf("%s\n", StringValueCStr(rbError));
  }

  ruby_finalize();
  return status;
}
```

The ruby script:

```rb
1.hello
```

When I run it now, I get this output:

```
undefined method `hello' for 1:Integer
```

This is as expected.
I then define this method:

```c
VALUE hello(VALUE self) {
  return Qnil;
}

// just after ruby_init()
rb_define_method(rb_cInteger, "hello", hello, 0);
```

When I run it now, I get

```
ruby: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000000b0
/* ... */
```

How can I handle the error here? `$!` is nil in this case but I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to initialise `status`:

```
int status = 0;
```

It looks like [`rb_load_protect` sets status if there is an exception, but doesn’t set it to zero if there isn’t](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_3_3/load.c#L848-L860), but by passing `&status` to it you are suppressing any unitialised variable warnings from the compiler.

What’s happening at the moment is `status` starts as some (non-zero) garbage, and doesn’t get set to zero if there is no exception, so the `if` block is always executed. However, if there isn’t an exception, then `$!` is nil, so calling `message` on it results in an unhandled exception which causes the crash.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I’ll try it out when I get home!